# android Application installed but not showing on screen

Tags: android, installation

My application is installed on real device as well on emulator but it does not display on my device screen as well on emulator screen. I mean to say here that whenever an app is run or installed on a device it opens up but here my app does not open it just installed and no error are shown or forced stop is not there. I even checked my download file where every app info is shown and it is present there. Can anyone help???? Thank you in advance.

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Info"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Info" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Help" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hide.Next"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_next" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hide.Next" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Is one of your activities designated as a Launcher?  Post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Maybe you don't declare the activity in the manifest, post your Manifest.

Comment: Hi Disguise, have you solved the problem? if so you should tell what's the correct solution

Comment: ok i am posting my manifest her.. and sorry all i didn't reply as i was on vacation.. :)

Comment: @Xingchen No, my problem is not solved..  when it will be solved i will surely post here.. :)

Comment: Thank you very much everyone.. i have found my mistake...  I haven't specified my action in launcher... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you specify the launcher activity for the app in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".YOURACTIVITY" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

More information here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have `<data android:mimeType="image/*" />` in intent filter of your Launcher activity, then remove it.

just place following two lines < action and category) as:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can see it in app list, but not shown on app screen, so I suppose you could be just missing 'android:icon="@drawable/your_app_icon"' setting in your manifest file.